# touchesEnded not called if i do not move finger

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, touches

I have a simple piece of code in which i have overridden touchesBegan,Ended,Cancelled(empty block) and touchesMoved.
If i click ( i'm testing on Desktop PC ) with the mouse touchesBegan it's called, but touchesEnded is called only when i move finger for a while. That makes impossible to recognize a single tap or a drag of the finger, and handle them differently.
I don't understand if this is an emulator problem or i am misunderstanding the whole process. Did you have the same problem?

I have a simple solution for my application, like check a "first move" variable in touchesBegan, but this is a pure technical question.

Thank you in advance.

This is all i use, apart from drawRect that it's not important.
I guess it's not a problem in my code.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.allObjects[0] as UITouch 
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self) 

    println("touchesBegan")

    if (Draw!){
        path.moveToPoint(touchPoint)
        path.addLineToPoint(touchPoint)

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.allObjects[0] as UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

    println("touchesMoved")

    if (Draw!){
        path.addLineToPoint(touchPoint)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.allObjects[0] as UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

    println("touchesEnded")

    if (Draw!){
        path.addLineToPoint(touchPoint  
        path = UIBezierPath() // Create new path for next line        
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please can you share the code you are using for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure this is an emulator problem.

Please see the code below. It works like a charm at my end.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    didMove = false;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    didMove = true;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (didMove == true)
    {
        //finger was moved
        NSLog(@"finger was moved");
    }
    else
    {
        //it's a tap
        NSLog(@"finger not moved it's a tap");
    }

}
```

While we are at it, can I bring your attention to UIGestureRecognizers? Try to use them since they make life a breeze.

Comment: Thank you, i already know UIGesturesRecognizers but i'm just practicing!